# In Arch Linux: Which is the equivalent to "apt rdepends" with pacman?

Tags: arch-linux, apt, pacman

I am trying to look for a packages that they depends of a knowed package. But I don't know the equivalent to `apt rdepends <package_name>`.

Comment: There is `pactree -r <package_name>` but it shows only the reverse dependencies of installed packages, not the repository not installed packages.

Comment: Check out https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman/Rosetta, under `Querying package dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Arch wiki, the equivalent would be `pacman -Qii <package_name>` if the package is installed, and `pacman -Sii <package_name>` if not. To search equivalents package manager commands check [pacman/Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman/Rosetta) on the Arch wiki.